# How to suppress randomly popping Korean characters in warning messages in R

Tags: r

Dear fellow StackOverFlowers

I am very beginner to programming languages. I've been mostly using `R` for the time series analysis for a course. I am taking this semester, and I've noticed that these random Korean characters pops up at error messages.

[image]

Could anyone please help me how to suppress this and force every error messages to be soley typed in English?

I would really appreciate your help.

Kind regards,
Jay

Answer (score 0):

To specifically stop those messages you are showing, you can use `suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(fpp))` in place of `library(fpp)`

However, It looks like you might have some other underlying issue, as that first line should be `attaching package zoo`